# Is there any use to water cool a raspberry pi?

Tags: hardware, overclocking, cooling

Is there any use to water cool a Raspberry Pi?

In other words, it is possible to overclock the RPi enough to have to water cool it?

Or will there always be enough with just the heatsinks, or with fan.

*If i overclock my RPi to the maximum, will it survive with just a heatsink?*

*If not, will it survive with a heatsink and fan?*

*If not, do you have to have water cooling for it to survive?*

I just wanna overclock my RPi to the maximum, just for fun. Before i do this, i wanna know if i need to have it watercooled. I dont care if my RPi is destroyed in the attempt.

Comment: This cant be a duplicate, i am asking if there is any need at all to water cool a RPi. Not if its possible.

Comment: Just because you cool something does not mean you can overclock it as much as you like. Eventually you will get to a point where the voltage is too much for the design and it will melt, burn and fuse. I think the most extreme cooling is liquid nitrogen -- but even then the clocks get out of synch and too many errors are generated. So it is pretty useless any way.

Comment: Yeah, thats my question, can i overclock my RPI so much that i must have it watercooled? I am not asking how much i can overclock it in mhz. You suggest that i think that i can overclock the cpu as much as i like, thats wrong. And that wasent my question at all. Since i know that i cannot overclock the cpu as much as i like, thats why i ask this question.

Comment: its not that bad a question, maybe lacking a little insight into how hardware works

Comment: Closed because the questions about whether it's even useful are addressed in the duplicate.  If you're interested in the questions addressed in your edit, you may want to completely overhaul the question and request it be reopened or ask an entirely new question.

Comment: I believe ppumkin's point is that there's no way you could overclock the pi enough to require cooling.  **It doesn't require any cooling to start with.**  You can tightly encase it in rubber if you want -- zero ventilation, no heatsinks.  Overclocking a reasonable amount will not significantly change that, and overclocking it an unreasonable amount will wreck the processor.

Comment: Its very simple, if you power it with 5W max. you cannot heat more than 5W. And 5W heat is really nothing to worry about, you don't even need a heat-sink. But be careful, don't overclock it too much as it is not all about CPU clock, that is complex topic.

Comment: Thanks for not helping me rephrase my question. Instead just close the question, calling it a duplicate.

Comment: As it stands, this question is more or less a duplicate of the previous question that will solicit answers that are too close to the original.  If you're interested in overclocking and the cooling considerations involved, at this point it may be better to ask a new question, but as it stands the changes made are not enough to make this a unique question (whether it's necessary to cool is covered in the duplicate).

Comment: well, in that case i dont even want to be a member on this site. Then i can do better without your "help". Demotivation doesnt help. But hey, there is other good sites out there, take care!

Comment: Hi Patchie. I also believe this question has been rightfully closed. If you have any reservations, take a look at the [faq]. If you want to discuss this further with us, please come to [chat].

Comment: its ok, i got help from another site, i was also in the RPI chat, thanks for nothing anyway..

Answer (score 1):

you should go for mineral oil =)

http://aquariuspc.it/eng_main.php

Comment: Cool page, but has nothing to do with my question at all.

Comment: Patchie... you put the Pi in the oil! And over clock it.

Comment: This was never my question at all. Don't you read my question, or is my english that bad?

Comment: Oh right :) You were asking if its safe to over clock it to the maximum as in raspi-config without heat sinks. Yes, otherwise it would not be an option. Like voltage tweaking (which is hidden) that kills the warranty and makes the Pi... fry .. and then die.

Answer (score 0):

Water cooling a Pi is overkill: http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=256779

Comment: You actually understood my question, but can you give me an example? i have tried to find some info in that forumthread, but cant find what i am looking for. First we have to find out how much maximum you can overclock a RPi, then find out if the cpu can survive with just a heatsink. Or if it might have to have a heatsink with a fan?

Comment: Overclocking the Pi to the extent where it would require watercooling is pointless. Watercooling costs more than the Pi! Unless you have a decent reason to do so don't over clock your pi at all. You can hit problems like quick SD card corruption causing the device to become unreliable. Overclocking limits depend on various factors, including which memory chips (manufacturer, not size) are on your Pi. Some scale better than others. The answer is not as simple as "you can clock by 2.5x". Other factors are involved. Perhaps if you had explained why you want to overclock you'd have better answers.

Comment: Well, i just wanna overclock my RPi to the maximum, just for fun. Before i do this, i wanna know if i need to have it watercooled. I dont care if my RPi is destroyed in the attempt. And if you dont know the answer, then thats ok, but then i must have to find it out on my own, or wait for better answers. But thanks anyway.